# Is "Paytm" payment gateway integration is possible in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, payment-gateway, cordova-plugins

Please help me is any possible to integrate "Paytm" payment gateway in phonegap. I am now creating Phonegap app for payment transaction and Paytm wallet also. So, i need to integrate with Paytm wallet please help me anyone who ever done with that integration...

Comment: Please tell any one who has integrate with Paytm and tell what the solution i will do.. reply anyone i post this question last week before.

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually i used this plugin
[paytm plugin](https://github.com/samyam-a/PayTM-PhoneGap-Plugin) and used this CLI to install

> cordova plugin add https://github.com/samyam-a/PayTM-PhoneGap-Plugin.git --variable GENERATE_URL= Checksum Generation URL --variable VERIFY_URL= Checksum Validation Url --variable MERCHANT_ID= MerchantID --variable INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID= IndustryType --variable WEBSITE= WAPWebsiteName

and use this plugin by calling like this in your js file

```
window.plugins.paytm.startPayment(txn_id, customer_id, email, phone, amount, successCallback, failureCallback);
```

its really helpful to me..

Comment: Thank you Hari Narayanan for reply. I am developing android app which will use payment gateways and I have to make it workable on devices android 2.3.3 onwards and ios as well with 4 onwards. Expecting your reply.

Comment: How did you manage to get user back to the application after successful payment with paytm? because I could manage users to redirect to paytm but successCallBack doesn't seems to be working. Is it working fine at your end?

Comment: compare with your customer_id and email or phone number after successful payment with paytm, i am compare with the phone number, customer_id and pass it to my server api, that makes unique Manoj Kumar.

Comment: what is txn_id and customer_id and rest parameter ? where we will be able to get that? Please let me know.

Comment: How will I create the Checksum Generation URL and Checksum Validation URL??

Comment: @karansharma Where you able to figure out the checksum generation and validation url ?